# Extend the borders of the detailSection to the bottom of the Acumatica report page

Tags: acumatica

I am wondering whether Acumatica report designer can extend the left/right borders of the detailSection to the bottom of the page - literally until next available section (such as groupFooter placed at the bottom of the page).

Take AR invoice (AR641000) as an example, I can add borders to detailSection2, however, since the height of this section is dynamically determined by the system based on the number of lines available in the original invoice document, borders will stop somewhere in the mid of the page.

Any advice is welcome, thanks!

Comment: You can use PrintAtBottom = true for any section but I think it will better to use PrintAtBottom = true only for the last section of the page

Comment: Thanks Petrosov for your reply. They prefer leaving the section somewhere in the middle of the page but just with extended borders no matter how many lines there are. Please have a look at the screenshot illustrating what they want: https://www.dropbox.com/s/74lw64z090pqvsd/borders.png?dl=0